# Tatable View multiple selection not working properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to implement multiselection in table view. But it is not working. When I add the below code it just shows me the single section for the elements in the table view. When I remove this line from code then I am able to select but not able to deselect the items.

**Removed line code:multi selection works but not able to deselect**

```
for (i=0; i<[arr_selectedCells count]; i++) {
  NSInteger currentValue = [(NSNumber *)[arr_selectedCells objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
  if (currentValue==indexPath.row) {
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  }
}
```

correct.

**Code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    UserFriend *user_friend=[arr_userFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=user_friend.name;
    NSLog(@"name is %@",user_friend.name);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<[arr_selectedCells count]; i++)
    {
        NSInteger currentValue = [(NSNumber *)[arr_selectedCells objectAtIndex:i]integerValue];

        if(currentValue==indexPath.row)
        {
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        }


    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(![arr_userFriends containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]])
    {
        [arr_selectedCells addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];

    }
    else
    {
        [arr_selectedCells removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];

    }

    NSLog(@"numr is %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    [tableView reloadData];
   }
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: where is the code for multiple sections ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these

```
tableView.allowsSelection=YES;
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

i just edited your code! and i hope it works for you

tableView CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    UserFriend *user_friend=[arr_userFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=user_friend.name;

    if([arr_selectedCells containsObject:user_friend.name])
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UserFriend *user_friend=[arr_userFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([arr_selectedCells containsObject:user_friend.name])
    {
        [arr_selectedCells removeObject:user_friend.name];
    }
    else
    {
        [arr_selectedCells addObject:user_friend.name];
    }
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];        
}
```